# How to convert an AVRO scheme into line protocol in order to insert data into InfluxBD with Apache Ni-Fi

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

I am creating a data pipeline with Apache Ni-Fi to copy data from a remote MySQL database into InfluxDB.

I use QueryDatabaseTable processor to extract the data from the MySQL database, then I use UpdateRecord to do some data transformation and I would like to use PutInfluxDB to insert the time series into my local Influx instance in Linux.

The data coming from the QueryDatabaseTable processor uses AVRO scheme and I need to convert it into line protocol by configuring which are the tags and which are the measurement values.

However, I do not find any processor that allows doing this conversion.

Any hints?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in processor for InfluxDB Line Protocol conversions - you could write a ScriptedRecordWriter if you wanted to do it yourself, however there is a project that already implements a Line Protocol reader for NiFi [here](https://github.com/influxdata/nifi-influxdb-bundle) by InfluxData that seems to be active & up-to-date.

See the documentation for adding it into NiFi [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#autoloading-processors)

Comment: Thanks for the link! The processors and controller services by InfluxData work fine.

Comment: @BerniHacker Awesome :) Please do accept the answer if it solved your problem to help others find it